# Problems Trying to Pretty Print XSLT Output

Tags: xslt, pretty-print

this is my first post so please let me know if I can make it more constructive in any way. I have read the forum guidelines so if I inadvertantly break them in anyway it will be nothing more than an innocent mistake.

## The Question

Is a simple one:

**How do I pretty print the output of an XSL file?**

But with some criteria:

1. **Using only native XSL functionality.**
2. **Without having to use a second XSL file to do a 'second pass'.**
3. **It must also work for elements with mixed content.**

I have googled this reasonably thoroughly but have not found a clear answer to this question. I have only used XSL for about a week so go easy if I have somehow missed the answer elsewhere.

---

### An Example

This XML...

```
<email>
    <attachedItem>priceless photograph.jpg</attachedItem>
    <attachedItem>important document.doc</attachedItem>
    <attachedItem>access codes.pdf</attachedItem>
</email>
```

...Transformed by this XSL...

```
<!-- Pretty Print Output -->
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<email>
    "Please find attached the stuff."
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</email>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attachedItem">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

...Produces this result...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<email>
        "Please find attached the stuff."
        <attachedItem>priceless photograph.jpg</attachedItem>
   <attachedItem>important document.doc</attachedItem>
   <attachedItem>access codes.pdf</attachedItem>
</email>
```

*Using the Saxon6.5.5 engine*

### Desired Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<email>
   "Please find attached the stuff."
   <attachedItem>priceless photograph.jpg</attachedItem>
   <attachedItem>important document.doc</attachedItem>
   <attachedItem>access codes.pdf</attachedItem>
</email>
```

---

## My Own Progress on the Problem

From the XSL above you will see I have discovered the use of `<xsl:strip-space>` and `<xsl:output>`. This meets the first 2 criteria but not the 3rd. In other words, it produces nice pretty printed XML without the mixed content, but with it I recieve the undesired output you can see above.

I know that the reason I get this output is because of the way whitespace is preserved in the source XML. White space is *always* preserved if it is part of a text node that contains other non-whitespace characters, regardless of the `<xsl:strip-space>` instructions. However despite my understanding I still cannot think of a solution.

Although I have addressed the first 2 criteria myself I would still like to know if this is the best way to achieve a pretty printed result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How would you like your Output to look like? Maybe show that. I don't think xsl:strip-space makes a difference here, because it would only process the input XML and not the Text that you write yourself hardcoded with the stylesheet. First thing you could try is add xsl:text around your email text `<xsl:text>"Please find attached the stuff."</xsl:text>`

Comment: Your output is not reflected in the stylesheet you show. You show one that produces literal `apply-templates` and `copy` elements because they are not prefixed.

Comment: @Mathias Müller Ah yes sorry that was just a typo, I've corrected this in the post.

Comment: @TobiasKlevenz Thanks for your reply, ommitting the `<xsl:strip-space>` results in there being an additional carriage return between each line. I believe this is because they will have been preserved from the source XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet produces exactly the output you request. The transformation was performed with Saxon 6.5.5. The correct indentation can only be achieved by meticulously typing all the line feed (`&#10;`) and space (`&#32;`)characters.

Note that pretty printing XML has no meaning when text content is concerned. The indentation of element tags can be easily controlled, but text nodes of elements with mixed content are always a problem. An application that takes XML as input should never rely on the exact indentation or whitespace handling of text content in XML.

In general, it is considered a bad idea to directly output literal text in an XSLT stylesheet. Always put text content inside `xsl:text`. `xsl:strip-space` has an effect only on whitespace-only text nodes of elements that belong to the *input* XML document (as suggested by @TobiasKlevenz already).

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <!-- Pretty Print Output -->
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<email>
    <xsl:text>&#10;&#32;&#32;&#32;"Please find attached the stuff."&#10;&#32;&#32;&#32;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</email>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="attachedItem|text()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<email>
   "Please find attached the stuff."
   <attachedItem>priceless photograph.jpg</attachedItem>
   <attachedItem>important document.doc</attachedItem>
   <attachedItem>access codes.pdf</attachedItem>
</email>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer @Mathias Müller, I'd consider the question answered now. Just one small thing though, I'm interested to know why you've matched on 'attachedItem/text()' as opposed to just 'attachedItem'? I thought the latter would have the same effect as the `<apply-templates/>` causes the `<copy>` to recursively copy all child nodes anyway. This should reproduce the text nodes without having to 'match' on them.

Comment: I do not match `attachedItem/text()`, the match is on `attachedItem|text()`, which means the template matches both `attachedItem` element and text nodes. You are right that text nodes are output anyway - but it is because it is the _default behaviour_ of Saxon to output text nodes. Apply-templates is very different from copy, it does not copy anything. Rather, it instructs the processor to do something like: "For any remaining child nodes of the current match, find other templates of your choice".

Comment: So, matching for `text()` is redundant really, if you simply copy the nodes without changing them anyway, but it is more _explicit_ to mention it.

Comment: I just noticed your first reply. I am aware of the functionality of apply-templates, however I feel the need to clarify, in my (limited) experience it is not actually the default behaviour for `<copy>` to copy anything other than the node it has matched. In the case of our template it matches 'attachedItem' meaning only the start and end tag of that node will be copied. See [link](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/xsl-elements/copy.html). This is why the `<apply-templates>` is required to copy the text as it has a 'built-in' template to handle this.

Comment: You need to read carefully. I was explaining that Saxon has a default behaviour in regard to text nodes, not the `xsl:copy` instruction. Yes, `apply-templates` is needed but not because it is "required to copy the text". `apply-templates` does not copy _anything_. It is needed in this case to allow the remainder of nodes that are children of the matched element to be processed. `apply-templates` does not have a built-in template rule for text nodes, Saxon has.

Comment: My apologies but your initial comment made it sound like you didn't understand how `<apply-templates>` made use of built-in templates, that is the key to copying child text nodes with a `<copy>` so I thought you would have mentioned it. Saying it is the _default behaviour_ of Saxon seemed to convey a misunderstanding, the way I would say it is that the default behaviour is defined in the XSL Spec http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule and Saxon is merely an implementation of that spec. But we are both entitled to interpret the situation differently as long as we understand :)

Comment: There is no need to be nit-picking beyond the point of understanding, so to say. But yes, also saying that Saxon did not come up with those rules on its own but adopted them from the spec would have been more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap "Please find attached the stuff." in an

```
  <xsl:text>
```

which would produce my assumption of your desired result, if not please post a 'desired output' example/.

Comment: Hi @tolanj and thanks for your answer, unfortunately this does not produce the desired output, it results in the top line looking like this `<email>"Please find attached the stuff."<attachedItem>priceless photograph.jpg</attachedItem>`. All on one line with no carriage returns. I've added a 'Desired Output' section to my post for clarification.