# Java - correctly indenting an XML made from multiple sources

Tags: java, xml, dom

I'm trying to correctly indent (indentation = 2) an XML file written by a Java Spring Boot application. The problem is that I'm not making up the XML myself, I'm creating the XML by joining parts of various source XML with different schemas.

My code is:

```
 TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  transformerFactory.setAttribute("indent-number", 2);
  Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
  transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
  
  transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");

  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(root.getOwnerDocument());

  StreamResult file = new StreamResult(outputFile);

  transformer.transform(source, file);
```

This seems to ignore completely the "indentation" parameter: it just copies whatever indentation was present in the original XML Files.

To copy the nodes, I tried both:

```
root.appendChild(document.adoptNode(extractedNodeToCopy.cloneNode(true)));
```

and

```
root.appendChild(document.importNode(extractedNodeToCopy, true));
```

But this doesn't change anything.

I don't get error messages, the result is simply indented as the original documents were (so every tag has a different style).

Comment: Indentation is only for human readers. So if it is important for you, re-read the resulting file, parse it and create a new output with proper indentation.

Comment: You can use XSLT transformation for the task.

Comment: The ugly thing is that I don't actually know what will be in the resulting file, so re-reading and parsing it properly isn't an option. How would I use the XSLT transformation in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You are using XSLT already. The code

```
transformerFactory.newTransformer()
```

instantiates an XSLT transformer with a default XSL template that performs the 'identity' transformation (see also https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer() )

So in your case to have indentation modified you could either

- use java to prepare the data in your DOM (stored in root). You would have
  to add TextNodes that contain whitespace to your taste, or
- do a similar job within a stylesheet (see also [Problems Trying to Pretty Print XSLT Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690468/problems-trying-to-pretty-print-xslt-output)) and make use of that by calling

  ```
    transformerFactory.newTransformer(your stylesheet)
  ```